# Currying Functions in Scala

Tags: scala, currying

I am new to Scala and I just started learning it and now trying some exercises. This one in particular I have a trouble understanding.

I understand up to the `(f: (A, B) => C)` part, but the rest I dont quite get it. Can someone please explain what's happening after the anonymous function part?

Thanks!

This is the function:

```
def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = a => b => f(a, b)
```

Comment: have you a reference where you get this from?

Comment: follow this http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala it will help you to understand currying

Comment: @pme, https://www.scala-exercises.org/fp_in_scala/getting_started_with_functional_programming

Comment: @rohitprakash yeah i've read this, gave me a bit of an idea thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `def curry` a method named "curry"
- `[A, B, C]` will deal with 3 different types
- `(f` it will receive an argument that we'll name "f"
- `: (A, B) => C)` that argument is type "function that takes A,B and returns C"
- `: A => (B => C)` "curry" returns type "function that takes A and returns function that takes B and returns C"
- `=` here's the "curry" code
- `a => b => f(a, b)` function that takes an argument (we'll call "a") and returns a function that takes an argument (we'll call "b") that returns the value returned after "a" and "b" are passed to "f()"